# A question regarding: Here is some medicine

Tags: grammar, articles, sentence-structure, british-english, spoken-english

My reference book gives me an example as follows:

> **Here is some medicine**.

To me, it does not make sense since ***some*** implies things more than one; thus, should medicine becomes medicines?

Having said that, should the sentence be written as:

> *Here **are some medicines***.

Comment: Think about medicine in liquid form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***MEDICINE*** can be   used both as a countable and uncountable noun.

So we can say: 
"Here is some medicine" (uncountable noun) or 
"Here are some medicines" (countable noun).

See the entry from [Oxford Dictionary:](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/medicine)

"NOUN

mass noun

A drug or other preparation for the treatment or prevention of disease.

‘give her some medicine’

count noun ‘your doctor will be able to prescribe medicines'"